# Why is it so easy to create bad performing queries with EF / Linq to sql

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm

I have been working a long time with linq-to-sql & ado.net entityframework. Each time we have a performance problem, it's almost always due to the use of EF / linq to sql. It seems so easy to write code that either fires a ton of queries or first fetches 1000 records to do some internal work before giving the actual result. Even with my knowledge & experience with this problem , I often find myself using some kind of a logical C# statement that fires a badly illogical performing query to the database.

A simple example:Let's say you have 2 tables Customer and Invoices. Invoice has a CustomerID to the Customer table

This will first fetch ALL invoice records from the database, then check if there is any record. If your customer has 1000 invoices, 1000 records will be sent from the database to your application

```
Customer.Invoices.Any() //or .Where or some paging statement or ...
```

The solution here is to query directly on the datacontext

```
db.Invoices.Any(invoice=>invoice.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID)
```

I'm sure there always is technical explanation and a solution to get around the problem but it seems so illogical that mappers make it so easy to screw up the performance of the application. These mappers are easy enough so any beginning programmer can use it, with all consequences. I've seen some more or less experienced developers that weren't even aware of the problem. Why don't I find any reference to this 'trap' on google? Ain't I seeing the right path to take ? Do other ORM's like NHibernate 'suffer' from the same problem ?

Comment: It sounds as though you are generalizing the problem based off a few experiences you've had lately, overlooking other problems you've had because they weren't as memorable. Your answer is basically that the computer will only ever do what it is told to do

Comment: This is a problem indeed. It is a design flaw. My solution: almost never use collection navigation properties. It is rare that you need all child entities unordered and no additional data at all. They are not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of what is known as the object-relational impedance mismatch.  There is no general solution to the problem other than hand-coding your SQL when it comes up.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

And yes, all ORMs suffer from this to some extent.  The best approach I've seen it is to create objects that represent declarative instructions for what data should be returned.  Only at the last moment do you combine all the instructions into a single SQL statement for execution.  I think this is basically what LINQ already does.

Comment: I have used Linq-to-SQL in the past and have never come across the scenario where I found I had to hand craft my SQL. That is not to say there are not cases where it would be necessary. However, this seems like an over generalised answer to me. It comes across as saying this is always the case.

Comment: That's not the intention.  The original post appears to be asking why this problem isn't just magically solved by some particular approach.  My answer is simply that there's no magic bullet.